# Python (unbound method wrongCommand.wrong)

Tags: python

Am currently having a bit of trouble with my code. I am making a very basic RPG, and have came across this problem:
(unbound method wrongCommand.wrong)
Am also running python 2.7.5, and windows 7.

Here's my code:

```
import os
class wrongCommand():
    def wrong():
        os.system("cls")
        print "Sorry, the command that you entered is invalid."
        print "Please try again."


def main():
    print "Welcome to the game!"
    print "What do you want to do?"
    print "1.) Start game"
    print "2.) More information/Credits"
    print "3.) Exit the game"
    mm = raw_input("> ")
    if mm != "1" and mm != "2" and mm != "3":
        print wrongCommand.wrong
        main();

main()
```

Comment: Is there a reason you've put `wrong` into a class? It would make more sense to have it be an independent function, defined at the top level of your file (though you might need to give it a longer, more descriptive name).

Comment: As a side note: You almost never want `class foo():` in Python. Use `class foo(object):`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first, you'd want to change

```
print wrongCommand.wrong
```

To

```
print wrongCommand.wrong()
```

(Note: addition of open and close parens)

But then you'd get the lines printed from the `wrong` method *as well as* the return value of that method, which is currently None.

So then I'd probably change

```
print wrongCommand.wrong()
```

To simply

```
wrongCommand.wrong()
```

(Note: dropping of the `print` statement)

Alternatively, you could have `wrong()` *return* a string, rather than print one, and then this line

```
print wrongCommand.wrong()
```

Would be fine.

---

You will either have to call the `wrong()` method off of a *class instance*, e.g.

```
wc = wrongCommand() # Create a new instance
wc.wrong()
```

or simply

```
wrongCommand().wrong()
```

In either case you'll have to change your `wrong()` method definition to

```
def wrong(self):
    #...
```

Or you'll get an error like "wrong() expects exactly 1 argument, got none".

Or you can define the wrong method as a class method or static method:

```
@staticmethod
def wrong():
    # ...
```

or

```
@classmethod
def wrong(cls):
    #...
```

Comment: Weird. When I tried what you suggested, I then get this:
TypeError: unbound method wrong() must be called with wrongCommand instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Comment: Yeah, you either have to call it on a class instance or make the method a static or class method -- one second, I'll update

Comment: Lol, I'm almost there! I have tried the first 2 ways you suggested. And have yet another error! >_>
wrongCommand().wrong()
TypeError: wrong() takes no arguments(1 given)

Comment: I take that back. I figured it out... I simply put __init__ in the def wrong in the class. it works.
and also tried the argument as self, and it worked. So I don't know if it doesn't matter what I put it there, or what. But it works. :P